# Camel moving files and directories

Tags: java, file, apache-camel

I have a camel route which consumes anything from a directory and moves this to another directory. The structure for one of the directories is *folder1 > file1 + folder2 > file1 + file2.* i.e **folder1** has 1 file and 1 folder in it and **folder2** has 2 files in it.

I want to be able to transfer the top level folder (folder1) as well as any files and folder below this. My route is as follows:

```
from("file://C:\\folderToUse?initialDelay=10000&delay=10000&recursive=true&delete=true").to("file://C:\\Destination");
```

What happens is that only **folder1** and the file within this are transferred, nothing else. I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` for **folder2** and the files here.

I presumed that having **recursive** meant it would transfer all these across before deleting but it seems after processing one it deletes everything before all processing has completed, is this correct? There is no other route consuming from this folder which may be taking those files and folders.

Comment: No Camel only deletes files, not directories, and it only delete 1 file at a time. I am not sure why it only does one file. Mind that on windows the slashes in the uri may need to be using double to escape them. Also you can try upgrade with latest Camel release etc.

Comment: I have another process to delete directories so I am not too concerned about that. I would expect that it would move all files, not just the first one it finds then delete the rest. I have double slashes already and I am running 2.13 anyway. I will try 2.15 and see if this helps.

Comment: Tried it on my PC and it worked fine.